# Is it possible to get the absolute URL of an image that is called by CSS in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am wondering if it is possible (but I have a hunch it's not..) to retrieve the absolute URL of an image that is loaded by a specific CSS class.

For example:

```
<div class="rabbit">
```

rabbit in css has a background image... how do I get that background image URL?

The reason why I ask on how to do this in Selenium IDE is because in my company we use it.

I am still googling and since I am not very proficient at JS, I could easily be missing a simple solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a quick pointer

You'll need to use storeEval to run some js and store the value, so look at the Selenium IDE docs for that

Then the js will be something like this...

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('hireme'),'').getPropertyValue('background-image');
```

if you run the snippet above, in the console on this page you should get something like this...

```
"url(http://careerscdn.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/careers2-ad-header-so-crop.png)"
```

Which will hopefully be good enough for any asserts you want to make

You'll need to replace the `document.getElementById('hireme')` with `document.getElementsByClassName('rabbit')[0]`;

Hope this helps, use comments if you need any clarification.

You may also need to add `this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().` before the call to `document.getElementById`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to use `window.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById("bubble-container"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");` (just an example) and also I had to rewrite the whole thing (some stupid encoding problem that caused an error: operation not supported.. lost over 2 hours on this :/) but thanks, it worked for me.